# Joomla Vote causing an error in Google Search Console : itemReviewed

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I found that using built-in in Joomla 3.10 **content vote plugin** is causing some errors on Google Search Console - itemReviewed.
I turned this plugin off - it helped, no errors.
I installed JVE free version ( Joomla Vote Extended ) ... the problem is back again.

Do You know any solution for this ? Is paid version working properly ? - I can not ask JVE developer (Viktor Vogel) about this problem because there is no email contact for users of free version :( ... only PRO version can contact.

Do You know any other easy free plugin that works properly with Google Search schema ?